# Angular JS: ngShow isn't binding my change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got an Angular module here within a larger rails project. I'm new to Angular and wish to avoid jQuery if I can (but do use it throughout the rails project and can use it if necessary). What I'm trying to do is hide a checkbox if the End Time is `""`, and show a checkbox if there's a value in the End Time. Unfortunately I have been unable to hide it if End Time is `""`. See:

[image]

You can see my HTML code below:

```
 <div class="control-group span8">
        <h4 class="pull-left"><strong>Active Hours (UTC):</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span1">
        <label class="control-label label-unstyled font-size-14"     for="inputStartTime">Start Time</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <select ng-model="geoRegion.start_time" id="inputStartTime" class="input-small" ng-options="thisHour.value as thisHour.name for thisHour in hours" value="{{geoRegion.start_time}}"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span1">
        <label class="control-label label-unstyled font-size-14" for="inputEndTime">End Time</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select ng-model="geoRegion.end_time" id="inputEndTime" class="input-small" ng-options="thisHour.value as thisHour.name for thisHour in hours" value="{{geoRegion.end_time}}"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span8">
                    <div ng-show="clearGeoSegment(geoRegion.end_time)"><label class="inline checkbox label-unstyled font-size-14"><input type="checkbox" id="clearGeoSegment" ng-model="geoRegion.clear_segment">Clear Geo Segment at end of active time period.</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span8">
        <p id="broadcast-notice" class="pull-left font-size-14"><strong>Note:</strong> If active hours is blank, the Geo Segment is always active.</p>
      </div>
```

My controller code (yes, I used jQuery. But please suggest otherwise!):

```
$scope.clearGeoSegment = (endTime) ->
  if endTime is ''
    $('#clearGeoSegment').hide()
  else
    $('#clearGeoSegment').show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't need to do the hide/show with jquery. You need to just bind to an expression that will be truthy when the checkbox should be visible. In this case it should be as simple as:

```
<div ng-show="geoRegion.end_time">
```

And you can delete your `clearGeoSegment` function entirely.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and works as intended! Any helpful resources on this? I wasn't entirely clear on how this ng-show/ng-hide works from Angular documentation. Thanks Peter!

Comment: Just the main angular docs and tutorial/guides. It is a very different approach and it just takes time and lots of small projects/experiments to grok how to work in harmony with AngularJS. Also note you can use `ng-if` to totally remove/add something from the DOM, which I prefer since it seems more semantically correct, but `ng-show` essentially accomplishes the same effect.